# CH34x board fails with avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00 Atemel Mega328P AU1640

Tags: arduino-nano, osx, ch340

I have been given a board(*Atmel ATmega328P-AU 1640*) to program. I googled and found category of board <strike>*Arduino Uno*/</strike> CH34x-based clone.

But when I program an empty program:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I get this error:

```
Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

These are all the ports that are available to me. I have connected my Arduino with one of the USB ports on my Macbook running MacOS Sierra

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do u thing that is an arduino

Comment: Because I was told @PeterJ I might be wrong

Comment: Why do you want to connect it via Bluetooth?

Comment: that's the only port available. Hey, I see this is Atmel's board....Do I need Atmel Software to code it? I'm not an electronics guy. Please fix(edit) this question if wrong

Comment: Can we see a picture of the board?

Comment: yes I can edit the question

Comment: check now @uhours

Comment: Why do you have the ICSP header coming off the bottom of the board?

Answer (score 3):

You have an Arduino nano clone using a CH340G chip for serial communication. You to down load and install a driver for your computer to recognize it. I don't use OSX, so there's not one I can recommend.

Comment: tell me for Windows

Comment: I also have windows installed in Bootcamp

Comment: I have installed both CH340G & CH341G but still, no other USB ports are showing except Bluetooth one

Comment: Sorry, I use Linux, and have the driver built in. If it's still not showing up, you either did it wrong, or the device is damaged.

Answer (score 3):

The board is an Arduino Nano clone, not an Uno.

1. Plug the Nano's USB cable into your computer.
2. Download and install the CH340 driver from here: http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html
3. In the Arduino IDE, select the port of your Nano from the **Tools > Port** menu.
4. **Tools > Board > Arduino Nano**
5. **Sketch > Upload**

If the port of your Nano doesn't appear in the **Tools > Port** menu (and no, dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port is not the correct port) then you may have a damaged or charge-only USB cable. Try using a known-good cable or verify that your cable works for data on another device. If you have it plugged into a USB 3.0 port on your computer then try a USB 2.0 port instead.

Comment: Yes usb 3.0 doesn't work I'll try with 2.0

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a clone of an Arduino Nano to me, with a CH340G chip as the USB interface chip.  You need to:

1. Install the CH340G drivers
2. Ensure that the ATMega328PU chip has a bootloader installed on it

The last Nano I bought from China didn't have a bootloader installed. There are many tutorials online for teaching you how to install the bootloader using another Arduino as the programmer.

Comment: can you post some links how to fix bootloader on MacOS? Also I have already installed CH340G. I saw a youtube video but it's still no showing me other ports. Please confirm what board category should I select thanks :)

Comment: how to check if bootloader installed on it or not....please provide me with some direction. I've no experience with electronics & Arduino stuff @Majenko

Comment: The led L should blink rapidly a few times when you press the reset button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instructions from install driver. https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver

Installation with Homebrew-Cask.

Then try this, and all work fine  ;)
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-fix-bad-Chinese-Arduino-clones/

Comment: Please don't post URL answers, write the gist of it and refer to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old driver by issuing one of the following commands (depending on your installation):

- sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/usb.kext
- sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext

Restart your Mac.

**Install with Homebrew-Cask**
Install the driver by the following commands

- brew tap mengbo/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver https://github.com/mengbo/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver
- brew cask install wch-ch34x-usb-serial-driver

Restart your Mac.

Try upload some code in your Arduino. 
In some cases the board might still not work.

This is because there is no bootloader installed on the Atmel microcontroller ship. To solve this problem we need a working Arduino and the clone Arduino we want to fix.

[![Make an ISP Programmer From Your Working Arduino
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfbYV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfbYV.jpg)

First we connect the working Arduino to our computer and open the Arduino IDE.

We go to File -> Examples and click ArduinoISP and upload this to the Arduino. Ones uploaded disconnect the Arduino.

**

### Connecting the Wires

**

[image: Connecting the Wires]

**Next we connect the wires from the working Arduino to the clone as follows.**

**Without 10 uF capacitor.**

Go to Tools -> Board and select the chinese board that is not working. in my case it's an Arduino Genius/Uno

Next we go to Tools again -> Programmer and select Arduino as ISP.

Go to Tools again and select "Burn Bootloader".

Go back to Tools -> Programmer and set back to ArduinoISP.

Your clone should work just fine now. ;)